# PHP + 1 really adds two

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I have the following PHP code loaded every time the page is refreshed. I am trying to update the views column +1 every time the page is loaded. To do this, I first retrive the previous views value from the table, then run another query to add + to that number. The problem that is occurring is every time I refresh the page, The code somehow adds two instead of 1. So instead of the $viewsA variable increasing by +1, it is increasing by +2.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Games WHERE pagename = '$game' ");

WHILE($datarows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):

    $title = $datarows['title'];
    $description = $datarows['desc'];
    $img_url = $datarows['img'];
    $cat = $datarows['cat'];
    $pagename = $datarows['page'];
    $rating = $datarows['rat'];
    $viewsA = $datarows['view_count'];
    $gameid = $datarows['id'];

endwhile;

$updateviews = $viewsA +1;


mysql_query("UPDATE  `trainw_games`.`Games` SET  `view_count` =  '$updateviews' WHERE  `Games`.`id` = $gameid;");
```

What do I need to change to make it only add +1 to the views column?

Comment: are you sure your script is not being executed twice per request?

Comment: You are getting the value from `$viewsA = $datarows['views'];` and updating `view_count`. Check the value of `views` if that field exists in the database.

Comment: +.5 doesn't work. It still adds Two. And how could it possibly be executed twice if it is outside the endwhile? Just asking, I am still learning about Mysql and PHP. Also, It was suppose to be view_count and I just missed that when I retyped it really quick on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that a `while` loop is appropriate for this problem. I would recommend to `echo $viewsA . '-' . $updateviews;` to see what the value is before and after the add.

But, why not just run a single `UPDATE` statement?

```
UPDATE Games SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE Games.id = $gameid
```

Of course, you should stop using `mysql_` functions and use either MySQLi or PDO:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Games SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE Games.id = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param($gameid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: +1 for your alternate solution, but its fun to find why it is doing that though!!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Comment: Do you have `mysqli` extension installed with your PHP instance? Otherwise try the old `mysql_query("UPDATE...");`

Comment: I probably do not have the extension installed. And when I tried the old update way you stated, It still updates by two. Thanks for your help though.. :/

Comment: @codman212 Have you tried putting in `echo $viewsA . '-' . $updateviews;` before your update statement? This will show you the views from the `SELECT` query and the views after adding `1`.

Comment: If the current number in the database is 10, It shows 10 - 11. Then When I refresh the page, It shows 12 - 13. Then refresh again, it shows 14 - 15.

Comment: Can you add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your `SELECT` statement?

Comment: After some thought, you say that you are still getting updates by `2` using an `UPDATE` statement alone. I am lead to suspect that you may be calling this routine more than once. Is this code being reused anywhere?

Comment: It still doesn't work. But it is probably something else in my page that is breaking it because if I let the page load slightly then cancel the load and refresh, it increments by one.

Comment: @codman212 That means the code is running twice. Do you wish to re-edit your question with more code?

Comment: Yeap I guess that maybe the problem causing this issue to add twice

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple rows in your database? If yes, it maybe caused by overriding the previous value.

For example:-

If first row the view_count is 1.
While the second row view_count is 2.

that overrides the the first row with 2 + 1 = 3
Which makes you thought increased by 2?

UPDATE 1: 
Ok, try this, put this

```
$updateviews1 = $viewsA + 1;
if ($viewsA < $updateviews1) { //execute the viewsA + 1 }
```

Comment: The table has 500+ rows, but each row is unique and only one row loads for each page, depending on the game that is loaded. For example, when someone visites, mysite.com/trainmaina, it loads the row with the exact name trainmania. Then a different row loads for mysite.com/earntodie

Comment: 'mysql_query("UPDATE  `trainw_games`.`Games` SET  `view_count` =  '$updateviews' WHERE  `Games`.`id` = $gameid;");'

Must be inside the if statement